# Get rid of quotation marks except for one column in CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file that has quotation marks around all the elements in the file like such:

```
"one","two","three","here comes "complex," column
with newlines and "\"quotes\""","five"
"six","seven",eight","nine","ten"
```

it is very complex & messy and I would like to remove all of the quotation marks in all of the elements except the complex column, which will always be column #4. It would be great to remove all the quotation but I find it hard to remove them since removing the quotation marks for column #4 often gives skewed .csv files

The output should look like this:

```
one,two,three,"here comes "complex," column
with newlines and "quotes"",five
six,seven,eight,nine,ten
```

I am specifically looking for

1. remove all the quotation marks except for column #6
2. there are newline, quotation marks and commas that are in column #6 that will be left as it is
3. Really would like to keep the format as it is and not replace any quotation marks with any other characters. Would like to just remove them instead of replacing them

I tried

```py
import csv

with open('example.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    rowreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='`')
    for row in rowreader:
        print row
```

but its not really what I am looking for

Comment: I saw the proposed duplicate but it didn't really follow my requirements. I have updated the post to clarify what exactly I am looking for

Comment: What do you expect the parsed data to be? As specified, I would expect the fourth column to be ``"here comes "complex`` (for a total of 6 columns), and the "columns" six to ten to be the next row of one to five - meaning that nine should be special-cased like four. Your description talks about #4 being special cased first, then only about #6 being special-cased.

Comment: so I want the `"here comes "complex," column\n with newlines and "\"quotes\"""` to be a single element in the .csv file and everything else just as it is without the quotes

Comment: How do you expect this to happen? The ``"`` around ``complex`` are not escaped, meaning the ``,`` behind it is a regular separator. You also have *two* closing ``"`` at the end for a total of five ``"``, meaning you have a dangling, unclosed string. You would get ``"here comes "complex``, ``" column\n with newlines and "\"quotes\"""``, or garbage.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry What I meant was I would like `"here comes complex, column\n with newlines and "quotes""` to be in a single element, clearly I am not very good at escaping them properly in my head

Comment: As discussed in your previous questions - what you're saying you have as input is not valid CSV per any "standard" and is simply not parsable by any tool as it's ambiguous. For example, there is no way to programatically and definitvely tell where your "complex" field starts/ends. You need to fix whatever is generating those files as they are fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just trying to help the OP understand the problem with his input format as he's asked half a dozen questions so far about how to parse it and there's simply no answer.

Given you have this input (I modified `,eight"` to `,"eight"` from your question to fix/simplify the example - it does not affect the issue):

```
"one","two","three","here comes "complex," column
with newlines and "\"quotes\""","five"
"six","seven","eight","nine","ten"
```

and that the 4th field of a record is wrapped in `"`s and can contains `"`s, `,`s, and newlines - how can **any tool** determine that the above means this:

```
Record 1:
    Field 1: "one"
    Field 2: "two"
    Field 3: "three"
    Field 4: "here comes "complex," column
             with newlines and "\"quotes\"""
    Field 5: "five"

Record 2:
    Field 1: "six"
    Field 2: "seven"
    Field 3: "eight"
    Field 4: "nine"
    Field 5: "ten"
```

instead of this (or something else):

```
Record 1:
    Field 1: "one"
    Field 2: "two"
    Field 3: "three"
    Field 4: "here comes "complex," column
             with newlines and "\"quotes\""","five"
             "six","seven","eight","nine"
    Field 5: "ten"
```

In both cases above field 4 is surrounded by quotes and contains quotes, commas and newlines. There is no way to programmatically tell which of the above interpretations of the data is correct given what you've told us so far about your input format.

In a valid CSV (see, for example, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 or the output from Excel) a double quoted field CAN contain commas and/or newlines without any problem but any double quotes MUST be escaped (either as `""` or `\"`) for the CSV to be unambiguous and so parsable by a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a correctly formatted .csv with quotes around every field, such as:

```
"one","two","three","here comes ""complex,"" column
with newlines and ""quotes""","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"
```

Then the default `csv.reader` will read it correctly, and the default `csv.writer` configuration (QUOTE_MINIMAL) will rewrite the the CSV as you want:

import csv

```
with open('example.csv','r',newline='') as fin:
    with open('rewrite.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
        r = csv.reader(fin)
        w = csv.writer(fout)
        for line in r:
            for i,col in enumerate(line,1):
                print(f'Field {i}: {col}')
            w.writerow(line)
```

Output:

```
Field 1: one
Field 2: two
Field 3: three
Field 4: here comes "complex," column
with newlines and "quotes"
Field 5: five
Field 6: six
Field 7: seven
Field 8: eight
Field 9: nine
Field 10: ten
```

rewrite.csv:

```
one,two,three,"here comes ""complex,"" column
with newlines and ""quotes""",five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten
```

In case you you backslash escapes for double quotes, you can help use the following `csv.reader`:

```
r = csv.reader(fin,doublequote=False,escapechar="\\")
```

This will read:

```
"one","two","three","here comes \"complex,\" column
with newlines and \"quotes\"","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"
```

See [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) in the `csv` documentation for more information.